# Any matrix ring $R_k$ is isomorphic to a subring of the ring $R_{2^k}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

I am reading the paper: ["Logical connections between some open problems concerning nil rings" by Jan Krempa.](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm76/fm76112.pdf)
I have a problem trying to understand the last part of Theorem 2. It says:
"Any matrix ring $R_k$ is isomorphic to a subring of the ring $R_{2^k}$".

I don't see why is that true and he is not giving any clue of that. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The paper deals with rings without identity, otherwise the very concept of nil ring is meaningless.

Comment: I think the clame is independent of the ring I consider. I mean, if the ring is unital, the claim have to follow the same way. Is it? Thank for the comment

Comment: Why should it? Rngs and rings are quite different animals.

Comment: I don't know. I'm new dealing with rings and rngs. That was my thought reading that. Do you have any proof or suggestion of why the claim is true? Thanks in advance

Comment: In short: the result is false if you're dealing with rings and subrings need to share the identity.

Comment: And supposing they don't share the identity, why is it true? That's what I don't see. I think @rschwieb is right. Do you agree?

Comment: If subrings need not share the identity, this is essentially obvious: if $m\le n$, then $\mathrm{End}(R^m)$ is (isomorphic to) $e\mathrm{End}(R^n)e$ for a suitable idempotent $e$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just map things in $R_k$ to matrices in $R_{2^k}$ which have the matrix from $R_k$ in the upper left hand block? You seem to be suggesting it’s ok that it does not share identity.

That's a subring isomorphic to $R_k$.

Comment: That set is closed under multiplication but it is not under adittion. Perhaps I am missing something. Could you explain a bit more your idea? Thanks!

Comment: I mean, the inclusion is not a ring map.

Comment: @EmilianoAcri Hm , I don’t know what I was thinking. Why I was suggesting only works for embedding GL(n) into GL(m) for m> n.  But I don’t understand your second comment. The inclusion is a ring map (but not unital, and you said that was ok?)

Comment: I tried to say that the inclusion from $R_k$ to the set you proposed is not a ring map because that set is not a subring, is it? I feel I'm missing something.

Comment: I deleted the part about non-unital. I That was a mistake because I was thinking on the generalities of the paper but this demonstration is nothing to be with that. Sorry about that.

Comment: @EmilianoAcri oh I see.  You were right, I edited accordingly.

Comment: I see your edition. Using that identification you're not using that matrices are of size $2^k$. It means that $R_n$ is included in $R_m$ as a subring if $n<m$. Is that correct? Perhaps Krempa uses this identification in particular because he can explode some properties. Thank you so much for your comments, there were very useful.

Comment: Sorry for my earlier lapse.i always appreciate that

Comment: @EmilianoAcri Maybe there is another way I didn't think of.